# How to read Json data with unbalanced array length in Python

Tags: python, pandas, database, api

I have been trying to fetch Json data from an API using Python so that I can transfer that data to sqlite3 database. The issue is that the data is unbalanced. My end goal is to transfer this json data to a .db file in sqlite3.
Here is what I did:

```
import pandas as pd
url = "https://baseballsavant.mlb.com/gf?game_pk=635886"
df = pd.read_json(url)
print(df)
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
raise ValueError("All arrays must be of the same length")
ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not obvious what you want your final DataFrame to look like, but appending "orient='index'" avoids the problem in this case.

```
import pandas as pd
url = "https://baseballsavant.mlb.com/gf?game_pk=635886"
df = pd.read_json(url, orient='index')
print(df)
```

You could also request the data with, for example, the requests module and prepare it before loading it into a DataFrame

```
import requests
url = "https://baseballsavant.mlb.com/gf?game_pk=635886"
response = requests.get(url)

data = response.json()

"""
Do data transformations here
"""

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

Comment: The oreint = "index" works. I am not sure about the second one, it still gives me the same error. Thanks!